# Entity Framework. Get all objects from table and print to the console

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to EF and im having some serious problems understanding the concept. I have a connection to database and it seems to work. I can add objects. Could some kind soul help me out with retrieving the whole table and then print it to the console.

This is how it looks right now;

```
namespace EntityFrameWorkExample
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        SampleDBEntities3 samp = new SampleDBEntities3();
        Cars c = new Cars();
        c.Brand = "Ford";
        c.Model = "P200";
        samp.Cars.Add(c);
        samp.SaveChanges();


        using (var db = new SampleDBEntities3())
        {

        }
    }
}
}


namespace EntityFrameWorkExample
 {
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Cars
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }


}
}

 namespace EntityFrameWorkExample
 {
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

public partial class SampleDBEntities3 : DbContext
{
    public SampleDBEntities3()
        : base("name=SampleDBEntities3")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Cars> Cars { get; set; }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `foreach(Car c db.Cars) Console.WriteLine($"{c.Brand} - {c.Model}");`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it stil does'nt work. I changed the name of the variable "c" to cars( c is already used  once). It gives error for the formatting.

Comment: problem solved! Thanks! foreach(Cars car in db.Cars) Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", car.Brand.ToString(), car.Model.ToString());

Comment: just a side note, you don't need to use ToString() on properties that are already string.

Comment: @Renato Afonso, your right, I did not think about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var info=DbSet<Cars>().ToList();
foreach(var a in info)
{
    Console.Writeline(a.Brand);
    Console.Writeline(a.Model);
    Console.Writeline(a);
}
```